# Building Kotlin TornadoFx into exe for Windows

Tags: kotlin, gradle, exe, tornadofx, launch4j

I have an application written in Kotlin and I used TornadoFx to build a GUI around it. As stated in the TornadoFx guide, I used OpenJDK11 and set kotlin.jvmtarget to "11". Here is my gradle build:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.30'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'java'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.9'
}

group = 'me.nicola'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application {
    mainClassName = "Engine"
}

javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.graphics']
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
    implementation 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.20'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-email', version: '1.5'
    implementation 'com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-jvm:0.15.0'

}

test {
    useJUnit()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class" : "EngineKt"
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName 'PrimaNotaHelper'

    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "EngineKt"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }

    with jar
}

launch4j {
    mainClassName = 'EngineKt'
    //icon = "${projectDir}/icons/myApp.ico"
}
```

I'm trying to use Launch4J to bundle my app into an executable for windows (.exe) and it compiles correctly when I launch the "launch4j" task, building the "lib" folder and the exe file. However, once I'm on Windows the executable does not work.

I also tried to use the Launch4J GUI for Windows and played around a little bit with that but nothing works for me: either It simply crash before starting or ask me for a different version of the JRE.

Can someone help me to set up my build correctly?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why don't you use jpackage which was introduced in JDK 14?

Comment: I tried to use JDK 14 but I had trouble integrating JFX libraries into it. So I sticked with openJDK 11. I solved using Launch4j anyway, I may give another try to JDK 14 in the future though, thanks for the reply!